# Макрос выдает ошибку "Macro function %SCAN has too many arguments." (SAS)

Tags: sql, sas

Макрос выдает ошибку, несмотря на то, что в `сolnames` всего 26 значений.

Задача макроса - создание `k` таблиц с 3 колонками: `End_of_the_period`, `Period`, <название 3 колонки берется из colnames> из таблицы `Month`.

```
%Macro TablesEc2 ;
proc sql;
%do k=3 %to 5;
create table intermediate&k. as
select End_of_the_period, Period, %scan(&colnames,&k.) From Month;
%end
;quit;
%mend;

%TablesEc2
```

UPDATE: Возможно , проблема в значениях `сolnames`, которые могут содержать буквы и цифры. Вроде `Semestr_1`, `Semestr_2`

Comment: судя по синтаксису ваш вопрос специфичен для какой-то СУБД. Добавьте тэг в вопрос

Comment: Здравствуйте. а у Вас есть макропеременная `colnames`? В вашем случае  макро функция [%scan](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/67912/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1nhhymw6gxixvn1johcfl6kaygw.htm) не так как вы хотите)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приведу пример кода для стандартного датасета [`CARS`](https://support.sas.com/documentation/tools/sashelpug.pdf) *(23 страница)* из библиотеки `SASHELP`:

```
%Macro TablesEc2 ;
    //Объявляем макро переменную
    %let macromake=;

    //Создаем датасет с перечнем всех производителей
    proc sql;
        create table Makers as
        select distinct Make from sashelp.cars;
    quit;

    //Добавляем к датасету колонку с идентификаторами
    data Makers;
    set Makers;
    rownum=_n_;
    run;

    proc sql;
    %do k=3 %to 5;
        //SQL запросом присваиваем макропеременной значение из датасета всех производителей
        select Make into :macromake from Makers where rownum = &k.;

        //Теперь создаем таблицу в цикле 
        create table cars&k. as
        //Выбирая каждый раз столбец с новым названием
        select &macromake From sashelp.cars;
    %end
    quit;
%mend;

%TablesEc2
```

**Однако**, этот тестовый пример выдаст вам ошибку по той причине, что в датасете `CARS` ***нету столбцов*** с названиями производителей. Это можно исправить, сделав свой датасет. Здесь я лишь показал пример как это должно работать.

Возможно вам будет легче изначально выбирать в SQL запросе столбец по какому-то условию и только затем в отдельном шаге данных  переименовывать его во всех созданных датасетах *(макроцикл в помощь)*.

Надеюсь,что помог Вам. Если есть дополнительные вопросы - спрашивайте в комментариях.

Answer (score 0):

```
%Macro TablesEc2 ;
 /*//Объявляем макро переменную*/
%let macromake=;

/*Создан заранее датасет с именами Semestr_1, Semestr_2 в первом столбце (vname)   и     соответствующими номенами 1 2 3 4 во втором столбце (n)*/


proc sql;
%do k=3 %to 5;
    /*//SQL запросом присваиваем макропеременной значение из датасета всех производителей*/
    select vname into :macromake from colnames where n = &k.;

   /* //Теперь создаем таблицу в цикле */
    create table cars&k. as
   /* //Выбирая каждый раз столбец с новым названием*/
    select &macromake From month;
%end
quit;
%mend;

%TablesEc2
```